# Cannot access rancid via web browser

Tags: apache-http-server

I have a `Rancid` with `apache` + `websvn` on `Centos 6.6`
I'm trying to login via web to this server to see config files, but the problem is that nobody knows password.

I found passwords in /var/rancid/htaccess. But they are invalid to access web.

Any Ideas where user credentials for access via web are stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The credentials are stored in `/var/rancid/htaccess`, but are most likely hashed. For example:

```
mtak@rubiks:~$ htpasswd -c test-htpasswd mtak
New password: banana
Re-type new password: banana
Adding password for user mtak
mtak@rubiks:~$ cat test-htpasswd 
mtak:$apr1$xm0Ptydq$RlHXaYRXHyoZKdUrKcDnj.
```

`$apr1$xm0Ptydq$RlHXaYRXHyoZKdUrKcDnj.` is clearly different from the password I entered (`banana`). The point of hashing is that someone who has access to the `htpasswd` file cannot find the original password. However, you can add passwords or replace them:

```
mtak@rubiks:~$ htpasswd test-htpasswd mtak
New password: banana2
Re-type new password: banana2
Updating password for user mtak
mtak@rubiks:~$ cat test-htpasswd 
mtak:$apr1$17CCL55Z$nBP8dG7gbX.2Bt4.ht/9w1
```

Comment: Thanks, that was it! I actually changed password but haven't noticed that it was not changed because i was not root

Comment: @eXPlosion Please mark this answer as correct (the checkmark on the left) if it solved your problem!